# Proof all eigenvalues of $P+(I-P)C$ are with positive real parts.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

$P=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T$($\mathbf{1}=[1,1,\dots,1]^T$), $I\in R^n$ is a indentity matrix, $C\in R^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Are all eigenvalues of $P+(I-P)C$ with positive real parts? How to prove that? (In other words, we should prove $rank(P+(I-P)C)=n$ and its all eigenvalues are with positive real parts)

With a random positive definite symmetric matrix $C$, I did 10 million experiments. All eigenvalues of $P+(I-P)C$ are with positive real parts.

Besides, I already prove that $P+(I-P)C$ is unsymmetrical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief answer that you will need to fill some details in.

1. Pick a new ON-basis such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf{1}$ is the first basis vector $[1,0,\ldots,0]^T$. No need to perform the change explicitly, all you need is to know how $P$ and $I-P$ looks like in the new basis.
2. The positive definite $C$ becomes a new positive definite matrix $C'$ that we partition  as
   $$
   C'=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}q & r^T\\\hline r & S\end{array}\right],\quad q\in\Bbb{R},\ S\in\Bbb{R}^{(n-1)\times(n-1)}.
   $$
   Prove that $S$ is positive definite.
3. The matrix in question in the new basis becomes
   $$
   \left[\begin{array}{c|c}1 & 0^T\\\hline r & S\end{array}\right].
   $$
   Prove that all its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Thank you! $S$ is the principal submatrix of $C$, we can easily prove it's positive definite. But for step 3, I cannot fully understand how to do it. Can you show me more details?

Comment: @HaoWANG The final matrix is block-triangular, so its eigenvalues are those of the blocks, i.e. $1$ and the eigenvalues of $S$. Now $S$ is positive definite, hence, its eigenvalues are positive. Clearly, all positive eigenvalues imply particularly that the overall matrix is of full rank.

Comment: Thanks, got it!